# handling intersection between selection markings

Tags: javascript

I have a **mark button** on UI, clicking which, any user selection is marked red. No problems here. I achieve this by `document.execCommand("insertHTML")`

But I have an additional requirement that if the new selection is created which is the intersection of old selections markings, old selection's red marking should disappear.

**As an example:**

In the following image: *this* and *testing* are marked. Now if I select *his is tes* from the start and click mark, old markings of *this* and *testing* should go away and only *his is tes* should be marked because there is an intersection.

[image]

code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 const s = window.getSelection();
  const selectionStr = s.toString();
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `<span class="bg-red">${selectionStr}<span>`);
})
```

```css
.bg-red {  
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
 this is testing  this is testing  this is testing
</div>

<button id="button">mark</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `startContainer` & `endContainer` of the selected text with `getRangeAt`, and compare them with `contentContainer`.
And if they are not equal with  `contentContainer`, then remove the `bg-red` class.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let contentContainer = document.getElementById("contentContainer");
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0){
    let startContainer =  selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
    let endContainer =  selection.getRangeAt(0).endContainer.parentNode;
    if(startContainer != contentContainer)
      startContainer.classList.remove('bg-red')
    if(endContainer != contentContainer)
      endContainer.classList.remove('bg-red')
  }
  const selectionStr = selection.toString();
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `<span class="bg-red">${selectionStr}<span>`); 
})
```

```css
.bg-red {  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer" contenteditable="true">
 this is testing  this is testing  this is testing
</div>

<button id="button">mark</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need IE support, you could use **selection.containsNode**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode

This allows you to flag the nodes that are contained in the selection. You need to set the **partialContainment** flag to true, so it'll detect nodes that are only partially selected.

So in a first time you flag the nodes that are contained by selection with a specific class name. Then you do your **execCommand** to apply your style. Then, you deleted the tags that were flagged previously by setting **outerHTML** on these nodes to **innerHTML**. You'll keep the style you just applied, but will remove previous ones. Like this:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const s = window.getSelection();
  const selectionStr = s.toString();

  tagIntersection(s)
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `<span class="bg-red">${selectionStr}<span>`);
  removeIntersection(s)
})

function tagIntersection(s) {
  const redSpans = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-red')
  for (let i = 0; i < redSpans.length; i++) {
    if (s.containsNode(redSpans[i], true)) {
      redSpans[i].classList.add('to-remove');
    }
  }
}

function removeIntersection(s) {
  // using querySelector because getElements returns a live nodelist 
  // which is a problem when you manipulate the nodes
  const toRemovespans = document.querySelectorAll('.to-remove')
  for (let i = 0; i < toRemovespans.length; i++) {
    toRemovespans[i].outerHTML = toRemovespans[i].innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editableDiv">
  this is testing this is testing this is testing
</div>

<button id="button">mark</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to detect if 'getSelection'.anchorNode.parentNode has class bg-red, and replace it, but too many side-effects appear.

So, the solution with regexp...

**(*1)** — If you inspect the code of content-editable element, you will see it's structure: Each new line is a separate div. You must replace each new-line symbol `\n` with "line-breaking" HTML, to allow multi-line selections.

**(*2)** — Browser inserts it's own corrections to HTML and prevents correct replacements. I was forced to insert any Non-HTML string, which is not likely to appear in text. And after all replacements - insert valid HTML.

**(*3)** — I recommend to analyze all regular expressions here → https://regex101.com/r/j88wc0/1 The main idea is to replace all double appearances of `<span class="bg-red"> anything instead of closing span <span class="bg-red">` or `</span> anything instead of starting span tag </span>`.

Note, that this code refreshes all innerHTML, each time you hit the button. It will not work as well with text from few thousand lines)

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let block = document.getElementById("block");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let s = window.getSelection();
  let str = s.toString().replace(/\n/g,'</span></div><div><span class="bg-red">'); // (*1)

  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `bubufication`); // (*2)

  block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML
    .replace(/bubufication/, `<span class="bg-red">${str}</span>`)
    .replace(/<span class="bg-red">(.*?)<\/span><span class="bg-red">/g,'$1<span class="bg-red">')
    .replace(/<span class="bg-red">(((?!<\/span>).)*?<span class="bg-red">)/g,"$1")
    .replace(/(<\/span>((?!<span class="bg-red">).)*)<\/span>/g,"$1"); // (*3)
});
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" contenteditable="true">
  <div>this is testing  this is testing  this is testing</div>
  <div>this is testing  this is testing  this is testing</div>
</div>

<button id="button">mark</button>
```